# 2009 Camry I4 Intermittent Random Indicator Lights, Car Shutting Off

Tags: toyota, cel, camry

Two days ago I had the `cruise control indicator` come on randomly while driving.  (I wrote it off to me accidentally pressing the button at the time).

Yesterday evening the car idled rough on start for a couple of seconds, rough idle stopped.

Today the `VSC OFF` light came on and stayed on.

A few minutes later, the `Charging System Warning Light` and Low Engine `Oil Pressure Warning` lights came on. The funny thing is that I don't know if the car turned off - I am guessing it did, but I pulled over immediately, so I can't say for sure. Steering did feel heavy, so I assume yes.

I turned off the car immediately, checked the oil (just filled, absolutely fine)
Turned car back on, it drove fine.

My only guess is ECM/connections to ECM. Any other ideas? How do I test this?

Edit: CEL on - two lean fuel mixture codes.

Comment: Numerous seemingly unconnected electrical issues screams battery, start by getting that checked out.

Comment: Any codes in any of the car modules? Does the check engine light work?

Comment: @Ben Two codes for lean fuel mixture, don't remember the exact code. CEL works. I don't think those are "real" codes - seems like a result of the electrical failure to me, though how, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely an electrical problem, however I don't believe its an issue with the battery itself. It sounds more like the wires in your wiring harness are arcing or the insulation on some wires is completely broken down and the current going through said wires is grounding through different, exposed wires or not at all (could create your issue by "thinking" a button is pressed when really a wire is just grounding through it, or connections get grounded before being able to perform their function). I would check your wiring harness for damaged wires or damaged insulation. Also check for water near the wires, especially where they connect to the ecu and at connectors as that can cause the issue stated above as well.

Comment: This could cause the oil pressure light to come on by grounding out the oil pressure sensor, simulate button clicks that you didn't make, throw various codes that the engine doesn't actually have, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered this was a question - re-charging the battery, changing out the spark plugs, and cleaning the MAF fixed this. I am guessing the spark plugs are what did it. Seems like there wasn't enough spark to keep the car running. Still weird to me, but the car has been running fine since whenever I posted the question.